# Combining objects if condition matches

Tags: javascript

I have an array `boxSize`  that has a total count of boxes for `small` and `large` boxes. I would like to combine these 2 separate objects into one if they have the same date and warehouse name

For example here is the `boxSize` array:

```
const boxSize = [ 
{ 
  warehouse: 'NYC',
  deliveryWeek: '2022-11-07',
  boxSize: 'small',
  total: 5
}, 
{
  warehouse: 'NYC',
  deliveryWeek: '2022-11-07',
  boxSize: 'large',
  total: 9
}
]
```

I attempted to loop through the array like this in the code snippet below:

```js
const boxSize = [ 
{ 
  warehouse: 'NYC',
  deliveryWeek: '2022-11-07',
  boxSize: 'small',
  total: 5
}, 
{
  warehouse: 'NYC',
  deliveryWeek: '2022-11-07',
  boxSize: 'large',
  total: 9
}
]



var obj = {};
for(let i = 0; i < boxSize.length; i++){

   var date = boxSize[i].deliveryWeek;
   // Get previous date saved inside the result
   var p_date = obj[date] || {}; 
   // Merge the previous date with the next date
   obj[date] = Object.assign(p_date, boxSize[i]);
}

// Convert to an array
var result = Object.values(obj);

console.log(result);
```

I am having trouble coming up with the logic and finding up examples to meet these requirements condition.

How can I end up with an array that looks something similar to this when the objects have the same `warehouse` and `deliveryWeek`:

```js
const boxSize = [
{
  warehouse: 'NYC',
  deliveryWeek: '2022-11-07',
  boxSizeSmall: 'small',
  smallTotal: 5,
  boxSizeLarge: 'large',
  largeTotal: 9
}
]

console.log(boxSize)
```

Comment: What's the point of this, though?

Comment: Oh combining the two? End goal is to display the data on table. Requirement is to have the data displayed in one row.

Comment: Does it have to be `boxSizeSmall`, `boxSizeLarge`, `smallTotal`, `largeTotal`, etc? I think just having an array like `details: [...]` of the combined detail in the objects would be easier to implement and use.

Comment: No I don't think it does as long as the data shows correctly at the end. I did not think of having a details array so I wrote out the desired object as that

Answer (score 1):

You could get a result like that by aggregating them with a map and then doing some transformations on the values like  this:

```js
const boxSize = [{warehouse:'NYC',deliveryWeek:'2022-11-07',boxSize:'small',total:5},{warehouse:'NYC',deliveryWeek:'2022-11-07',boxSize:'large',total:9}];

const keyFor = (item) => `${item.warehouse}:${item.deliveryWeek}`;

const map = new Map();

boxSize.forEach((box) => {
    const key = keyFor(box);
    
    if (!map.has(key)) map.set(key, []);
    
    map.get(key).push(box);
});

const result = Array.from(map).map(([, values]) => ({
    warehouse: values[0].warehouse,
    deliveryWeek: values[0].deliveryWeek,
    ...values.reduce((obj, item) => ({
        ...obj,
        ["boxSize" + item.boxSize[0].toUpperCase() + item.boxSize.slice(1)]: item.boxSize,
        [item.boxSize + "Total"]: item.total,
    }), {}),
}));

console.log(result);
```

but this is really complicated and it's hard to use the resulting object in practice. Also, duplicate entries will be overwritten by the latest entry... I recommend using an array in the resulting object to avoid all of these:

```js
const boxSize = [{warehouse:'NYC',deliveryWeek:'2022-11-07',boxSize:'small',total:5},{warehouse:'NYC',deliveryWeek:'2022-11-07',boxSize:'large',total:9}];

const keyFor = (item) => `${item.warehouse}:${item.deliveryWeek}`;

const map = new Map();

boxSize.forEach((box) => {
    const key = keyFor(box);
    
    if (!map.has(key)) map.set(key, []);
    
    map.get(key).push(box);
});

const result = Array.from(map).map(([, values]) => ({
    warehouse: values[0].warehouse,
    deliveryWeek: values[0].deliveryWeek,
    details: values.map(({ boxSize, total }) => ({ boxSize, total })),
}));

console.log(result);
```

which is arguably easier to implement and use compared to the former.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let boxSize = [ 
{ 
  warehouse: 'NYC',
  deliveryWeek: '2022-11-07',
  boxSize: 'small',
  total: 5
}, 
{
  warehouse: 'NYC',
  deliveryWeek: '2022-11-07',
  boxSize: 'large',
  total: 9
}
]

let combinedBoxes = [];


for(let i = 0; i < boxSize.length; i++){
  
  let currentBox = boxSize[i];
  
  let boxes = boxSize.filter(box => box.warehouse == currentBox.warehouse && box.deliveryWeek == currentBox.deliveryWeek)
  
  let small = boxes.filter(box => box.boxSize == "small")[0]
  let large = boxes.filter(box => box.boxSize == "large")[0]
      
  combinedBoxes.push({
    warehouse: currentBox.warehouse,
    deliveryWeek: currentBox.deliveryWeek,
    smallTotal: small.total,
    largeTotal: large.total
  })
  
  boxSize = boxSize.filter(box => box.warehouse != currentBox.warehouse && box.deliveryWeek != currentBox.deliveryWeek)
}

console.log(combinedBoxes)
```